# Laravel 5.1 post requests not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5.1

In my Laravel project when running `php artisan serve` everything work as expected. but when I use apache the post requests are not working and I'm just getting a response with status code 500.

anyone can help me solving this? thanks in advance

Comment: White Screen of Death or 500 Internal Server Error? Check your error log.

Answer (score 1):

To get more info on the error, enable debug mode.

In `.env`(preferred):

```
APP_DEBUG=true
```

or in `config/app.php`:

```
'debug' => true,
```

This will enable displaying stack traces in the response on errors like this.

You can also have a look into `app/storage/logs/laravel.log` to see what error you have.

Comment: debug mode is enabled. and like I said in the question, everything is working well when I use artisan serve. The problem is related to apache

Comment: Changing environments can cause errors in Laravel too. I've pointed out how to get more info because as it stands, there's not enough info to fix the problem. Also check apache's error_log

Comment: I checked apache error log and there was an error with failed to open stream message. I just changed the permission and it is now working. thanks @bernie